# Date (time of year) of the Iliad?

Tags: homer, iliad, calendar-dates

Does Homer give any clue as to the time of year, or even the specific dates, when events in the *Iliad* occur? I don't mean the absolute chronology (e.g., 1184 BCE or whatever) or span of time (e.g., +9 days for the plague), but rather the time within the year (e.g., the first day of autumn, 12th June, etc.).

Comment: There was a fascinating article, which I need to find again, analyzing the astronomy of the Odyssey and what it could tell us about the chronology. There are a couple mentions of season but this article put together a surprisingly thorough timeline based on the mentions of stars and planets (both literal and metaphorical—how much Homer meant the latter is a good question).